# A lower bound for the cosine integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bounds-of-integration

I am reading Devroye's paper 2001Simulating Perpetuities. On P103, he mentioned a lower bound for cosine integral, i.e.,
$$\int_0^t\frac{1-\cos s}{s}ds \geq max(0,\gamma+\log t),$$
where $\gamma$ is 0.5 less than Euler's constant.

I checked the reference he cited, but did not see how I can get to the equation. Wondering someone could help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{1-\cos (s)}{s}\,ds =\log (s)-\text{Ci}(s)$$
$$\int_0^t\frac{1-\cos (s)}{s}\,ds =\gamma+\log (t)-\text{Ci}(t)$$ and the largest value of
$\text{Ci}(t)$ is about $0.47200$

Comment: Thanks for that. By the way, is there any reference on the largest values and zeros of $Ci(t)$. I am wondering how to do the calculations here, since we do not know the exact integration result.

Comment: @gouwangzhangdong. I did not find references but it could be simple to generate tables. Up to which $t$ would you like to have them ?

Comment: No worries. I can generate tables by myself. Many thanks for your help. The extremas of $Ci(t)$ can be seen easily by differentiation and it can be proved that $Ci(\frac{\pi}{2})$ is the global maximum. Saddly, I cannot prove it is smaller than $\frac{1}{2}$ theoretically, and have not seen it anywhere.